# Can I free the memory of the char* string when I assign it to std::string?

Tags: c++, string, free, stdstring

Can I free the memory of the char* pointed string after I have convert it to a std::string?
For example:

```
char* c_string;
c_string = strdup("This is a test");
std::string cpp_string;
cpp_string(c_string);
free(c_string); /* can I call free here? */
```

Comment: vs2012 is happy with above code except ``std:string``.

Comment: @gongzhitaao Just because code compiles doesn't mean that it is correct. You could still be relying on undefined behavior. And `std::string` is perfectly valid in C++. You probably just forgot to include `<string>`.

Comment: @It compiles and runs correctly.  I suppose if it could not be freed then some runtime error will occure.  What's more, What I mean is ``std:string`` instead of ``std::string``. See the typo?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. `std::string` copies the underlying C string.

<sup>Source: Table 67 of §21.4.2 of C++11 draft N3376.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The `std::string` constructor makes a copy of the string passed to it.

See constructor #4 on [this page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/).

```
string (const char* s);    // from c-string
```

> **from c-string**
>
> Copies the null-terminated character sequence (C-string) pointed by s.